# Fahrenheit into Celcius conversion and keeping them as pairs

Tags: dictionary, arraylist

I have a long array list of temperature in Fahrenheit like this (one mean value for every hour):

```
[ 51, 54, 57, 62, 67, 74, 77, 84, 85, 88, 86, 78, 77, 74, 71, 67, 64, 62, 59, 55, 54, 53, 54, 52]
```

I want to convert them to Celcius first by using  `(F − 32) * 5/9`   on the internet there are ready solutions for this conversion part but I could not see something close to this specific one

Then I want to keep them as pairs (could be map, hashmap doesn't matter)

```
51 : 10.5, 54 : 12.2, 57 : 13.8, . . . 88 : 31.1, . . , 54 : 12.2, 52 : 11.1
```

I can't write the code, somehow I know a bit about each part but can not produce an outcome. Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: You don't need any hashmap nor dictionary. All you need is to turn every Fahrenheit temperature into a pair of (Fahrenheit,Celsius) values. Besides, I suppose you'll want to preserve the order of the values: losing that amounts to forget when the temperatures were measured. I don't suppose you're willing to lose that information, are you?
Since this looks like homework, I'll let you do the rest.

Comment: Yes its a personal project,  I want to keep the order of values. I tried things but I think I will stick to python as coding with java won't be maintainable with with my restricted knowledge

Comment: Frankly you don't need to store anything. Why don't you call a function to convert your temperatures whenever needed? It would require no extra coding and be more efficient on every level.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. with javascript:

```js
const obj = {};

[51, 54, 57, 62, 67, 74, 77, 84, 85, 88, 86, 78, 77, 74, 71, 67, 64, 62, 59, 55, 54, 53, 54, 52].forEach(F => {
    obj[F] = +((F - 32) * 5/9).toFixed(1);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Even though the OP mentioned hashmaps, the point is to store temperature measurements, not a Fahrenheit to Celsius partial conversion table!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can make a list of [tuples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). (A dictionary won't work, because the keys must be unique, so you can't have 2 seperate entries for 54, for example).

Tuples are indicated by an extra set of parentheses, you can see them in the line where ioTuple is set (to say: Put these two values together in one tuple), and they also show up in the output below.

I used a function to handle the formula (and rounding). Then used a for-loop over the input list to put it all together. Of course there are many other ways to achieve the same result.

```
inputList =  [51, 54, 57, 62, 67, 74, 77, 84, 85, 88, 86, 78, 77, 74, 71, 67, 64, 62, 59, 55, 54, 53, 54, 52]
outputList = []

def fahrenheit_to_celsius(inputF):
    c = (inputF - 32) * 5 / 9
    cRounded = round(c, 1) # Round to one decimal place
    return cRounded

for i in inputList:
    ioTuple = (i, fahrenheit_to_celsius(i))
    outputList.append(ioTuple)

print(outputList)
```

prints the result:

```
[(51, 10.6), (54, 12.2), (57, 13.9), (62, 16.7), (67, 19.4), (74, 23.3), (77, 25.0), (84, 28.9), (85, 29.4), (88, 31.1), (86, 30.0), (78, 25.6), (77, 25.0), (74, 23.3), (71, 21.7), (67, 19.4), (64, 17.8), (62, 16.7), (59, 15.0), (55, 12.8), (54, 12.2), (53, 11.7), (54, 12.2), (52, 11.1)]
```

(If you intend on using this to run your industrial nuclear power plant, please notice that my code makes (57, 13.9), where as your example says 13.8. I'll assume however this is outside the scope of this question ;-> )

Comment: Ahaha, thank you. no I won't use it in nuclear power, thank you for answer I solved this in python by using first map and then dict(zip(Flist and Clist).This is a part of a web scraping project to keep daily hourly temperatures and I tried solving it with java and stuck as my java knowledge is very basic and I felt helpless.

Answer (score 0):

```
fahrenheit_list = [51, 54, 57, 62, 67, 74, 77, 84, 85, 88, 86, 78, 77, 74, 71, 67, 64, 62, 59, 55, 54, 53, 54, 52]

print(tuple(zip(fahrenheit_list, list(map(lambda f : round((f - 32)*(5/9),1), fahrenheit_list)))))
```

I will be switching back to python though in the project to automate with selenium, I thought java would be more appropriate but lack of knowledge wont help to maintain it in the future.

thank you